# C# GUI приложение под Linux

Tags: c#, linux

Похожий вопрос вроде был 3 года назад, но может что-то уже изменилось...

MS Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition поддерживает создание приложений C++ Linux. Но есть готовый проект C# WPF под Windows, который хотелось бы перебилдить под Linux. Я знаю, что можно просто запустить с Mono и т.д. Но стоит задача именно приложения под Linux.

Поддерживает ли Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition именно C# GUI для Linux ?

Comment: В природе нет версии WPF под Linux. Опция с mono - это WinForms. Также есть проект [Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia) - это тоже что то, основанное на XAML и привязках - можете поглядеть в эту сторону. Но вот именно от MS для Linux ничего с GUI пока нет.

Answer (score 4):

Есть аналог WPF под Windows, Linux и MacOS - [Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net), правда ещё не совсем релизная версия, но на неё уже пишут софт. По ссылкам ниже сть статьи и видео.

Но вот по быстрому перенести готовый проект вряд ли получится.

[Релиз кросс-платформенного .NET UI-тулкита AvaloniaUI 0.8](https://habr.com/ru/post/447152/)

[На злобу дня: кроссплатформенный клиент для Telegram на .NET Core и Avalonia](https://habr.com/ru/post/354646/)

[Исходники Telegram client](https://github.com/egramtel/egram.tel)

[Видео: Никита Цуканов — AvaloniaUI — первый кроссплатформенный XAML UI-фреймворк с поддержкой .NET Core](https://youtu.be/8qzqweimcFs)

Comment: Я скачал Avalonia, знаю, что нужно как обновление установить в MS Visual Studio. У меня 2015 Professional. Можете подсказать, как поставить?

Comment: @AVM, имеете ввиду, что вы хотите установить расширение для студии, чтобы можно было проекты создавать? То есть, которое добавляет шаблоны проектов? Например, как по этой ссылке: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AvaloniaTeam.AvaloniaforVisualStudio

Comment: Я спрошу так - куда нужно поместить AvaloniaVS.vsix чтобы Visual Studio его увидела? Возможно ли это для Visual Studio 2015 Professional ?

Comment: По ссылке написано: Works with Visual Studio 2017, 2019. Видимо, с 2015 не работает. А вообще *.vsix нужно запустить двойным кликом, помещать его никуда не нужно. Так же можно вообще это всё не устанавливать, а подключить библиотеки через NuGet или скачать исходники, собрать и создать рядом свой проект. Далее можно будет дебажить и свой проект и сам фреймворк (думаю, такая возможность только в плюс, так как будет понимание, что происходит). Только если скачивать фреймворк, нужно после этого переключиться на релизную ветку и с ней работать (речь о Git).

Comment: Я уже запускал ее двойным кликом, вылезло окно ошибки: "Это расширение не может быть установлено ни для одно из установленных продуктов". А Visual Studio 2017, 2019 любая эдишен поддерживается?

Comment: @AVM, поставьте себе VS 2019 Community Edition. Ей можно пользоваться для коммерческой разработки, но там есть ограничения, их нужно читать. Ограничения на размер команды и прибыль в год, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Спасибо, можно попробовать.

Comment: А разработка в линуксе для нее уже сделана? Или пока что в студии сидеть?

Comment: @JohnnyRage, есть телеграмм чат, там в нём есть один из разработчиков -- Никита Цуканов. Лучше него вряд ли кто-то ответит: https://t.me/Avalonia